# what are computational macros and syntax macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I was reading the paper "An Object oriented preprocessor fit for C++".

"http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/st/lehre/Arte-fakt/Seminar/papers/17/An%20Object-Oriented%20preprocessor%20fit%20for%20C++.pdf"

It discusses three different types of macros.

1. text macros. // pretty much the same as **C** preprocessor
2. computational macros // text replaced as a result of computation
3. syntax macros. // text replaced by the syntax tree representating a linguistically consistent construct.

Can somebody please explain the last two type of macros in an elaborate way. 
It says that inline functions and templates are examples of computational macros, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the original Cheatham's paper from 1966 that the Willink's and Muchnick's paper refer to I'd summarize the different macro types like this:

1. Text macros do text replacements before scanning and parsing.
2. Syntactic macros are processed during scanning and parsing. Calling a syntax macro replaces the macro call with another piece of AST.
3. Computational macros can happen at any point after the AST has been built by the scanner and the parser. The point is that at this point we are no longer processing any text but instead manipulating the nodes of the AST i.e., we are dealing with objects that might already even have semantic information attached to them.

I'm no C++ internals expert but I'd assume that the inlining of function calls and instantiating templates is about manipulating the syntax tree before, while and after it's been annotated with semantic information necessary to compile it properly as both of those seem to assume knowing a lot of stuff (like type info and if something is good to be inlined) that is not yet known during scanning and parsing.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i also read the paper a few days back.

Answer (score 1):

By 2. it sounds like they mean that some computation is done at compile time and the resulting instructions executed at runtime only involve the result. I wouldn't think inline functions particularly represent this, but template meta-programming does exactly this. Also `constexpr` in C++11.

I think 3. could also be represented by the use of templates. A template does represent a syntax tree, and instantiating it involves taking the generic syntax tree, filling in the parameterized, unknown bits, and using the resulting syntax tree.